# Resource style not found android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Hi so while compiling a project in android studio i keep getting errors saying resource style not found and im a beginner and i dont really know how to fix it. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: You need to edit your question and copy-paste your `style.xml` file. Apparently, the `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` cannot be found. Also, let us know which class is your MainActivity extending i.e. `AppCompatActivity` or `Activity`

Comment: hi so i somehow added the theme.appcombat.notitlebar and the rest and it worked but now im getting some other errors

Answer (score 0):

Check ***AndroidManifest.xml*** file and replace any lines like:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

with:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

If your app depends on other modules, you should also check *AndroidManifest.xml* from those modules too.
This could solve the compile error. But if You are extending your activity class from the support library, i.e. `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{...}` , you should use a support theme i.e.

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar"
```

Otherwise, it causes application to crash.